# Crawler skipping a whole lead if it doesn't find either of certain elements

Tags: python, web-crawler

I got an issue running my python crawler. When it finds any of the item missing
then it skips the whole lead. More specifically if it doesn't find name from a page then it doesn't care about address, web, email etc rather it skips that page and print nothing. How can i fix it the way so that any item is missing then the crawler will print the rest? I have pasted the crawler code with a url. Hope there is any workaround.

Here is what i tried with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
def Endpoint(address):
    page=requests.get(address)
    tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//div[@class="contact-details block dark"]')
    for title in titles:
        try:
            Name=title.xpath('.//p[1]/text()')[0]
            Name1=title.xpath('.//p[3]/text()')[0]
            Name2=title.xpath('.//p[1]/text()')[1]
            Name3=title.xpath('.//p[1]/text()')[2]
            Address = title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')[0]
            Address1 = title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')[1]
            Address2 = title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')[2]
            Address3 = title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')[3]
            Web = title.xpath('.//p/a/@href')[0]
            Email = title.xpath('.//p/a/@href')[1]
            Metco=(Name,Name1,Name2,Name3,Address,Address1,Address2,Address3,Web,Email)
            print(Metco)
        except:
            continue


Endpoint("http://www.austrade.gov.au/SupplierDetails.aspx?ORGID=ORG8160044466&folderid=1736")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this issue if you set a default value ( eg `None` ) , so it won't throw an exception if an item is not in range

```
import requests
from lxml import html

def Endpoint(address):
    page=requests.get(address)
    tree=html.fromstring(page.text)
    titles = tree.xpath('//div[@class="contact-details block dark"]')
    for title in titles:
        try :
            Name=title.xpath('.//p[1]/text()')[0] if len(title.xpath('.//p[1]/text()')) > 0 else None
            Name1=title.xpath('.//p[3]/text()')[0] if len(title.xpath('.//p[3]/text()')) > 0 else None
            Name2=title.xpath('.//p[1]/text()')[1] if len(title.xpath('.//p[1]/text()')) > 1 else None
            Name3=title.xpath('.//p[1]/text()')[2] if len(title.xpath('.//p[1]/text()')) > 2 else None
            Address = title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')[0] if len(title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')) > 0 else None
            Address1 = title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')[1] if len(title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')) > 1 else None
            Address2 = title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')[2] if len(title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')) > 2 else None
            Address3 = title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')[3] if len(title.xpath('.//p[2]/text()')) > 3 else None
            Web = title.xpath('.//p/a/@href')[0] if len(title.xpath('.//p[1]/text()')) > 0 else None
            Email = title.xpath('.//p/a/@href')[1] if len(title.xpath('.//p[1]/text()')) > 0 else None
            Metco=(Name,Name1,Name2,Name3,Address,Address1,Address2,Address3,Web,Email)
            print(Metco)
        except Exception as ex :
            print ex

Endpoint("http://www.austrade.gov.au/SupplierDetails.aspx?ORGID=ORG8160044466&folderid=1736")
```

Result

> 'Company Name: PIMS Group Pty Ltd', None, 'Phone: +61 7 4969 3900', 'Fax: +61 7 4969 3999', '43 Evans Avenue', 'North Mackay', 'QLD', '4740', 'mailto:admin@pims.net.au', 'http://www.pims.net.au'

Comment: Thanks sir t.m.adam, for your robust, flawless and effective solution. I'm very unhappy that I could not upvote your answer thousand times. Thanks again.

Comment: @t.m.adam You should really use [ItemLoader](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html) instead.

Comment: @Granitosaurus thanks , but i 'd rather not use any extra , non - standard libs . Good suggestion though

Comment: @t.m.adam oh sorry, thought this was tagged with scrapy. Nevertheless ItemLoaders shows a good example how to keep your parsing code clean. combining xpath, if and other python logic is a pretty quick way to lose your head.